# Open vim with settings

Tags: vim

Is there a way to open vim with a couple settings enabled from the command line? In particular, I want to set the following options

```
:set nowrap
:call clearmatches()
```

I have syntax highlighting setup, and not calling either of these two makes the text appear red, and for files with long lines, unreadable. If there is a way to open vim with these two settings enabled, I would like to alias that command for reading regular, non-syntax files.

Comment: Why not add these to your `.vimrc` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I only want to enable these settings when I open particular files, so in the default case, I would like these settings to _not_ apply. Thanks.

Comment: There is a `-c` or `--cmd` command line option to `vim`. But these will apply *before* processing any startup file.

Comment: What did you find when you did `$ vim --help`?

Comment: @romainl Thanks, figured it out from that.

Answer (score 2):

From the `--help` prompt as pointed to above. This works

```
vim  -c "set nowrap" -c "call clearmatches()" <file>
```